# Ogg Vorbis wrapper in Python for Windows

Tags: python, windows, audio, ogg

I've found a small program written in Python which helps me to solve one problem. This program uses PyOgg wrapper to work with Ogg files. PyOgg was written for unix-based systems. Can you tell me if there's any Python Ogg wrapper for Windows? Or maybe anybody can help me to compile PyOgg under Windows?

Comment: If you can convert ogg to wav, the winsound module could help

Answer (score 0):

Try [audiolab](http://www.ar.media.kyoto-u.ac.jp/members/david/softwares/audiolab/sphinx/installing.html).